# How to call Plugin within a plugin call in PyroCMS

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

I have a plugin called "query" and it is called via the format: `{{ query:run query="SELECT * FROM table" }}`
I want to make repetitive call to the same plugin depending on the output of the previous call. The code is as follows:

```
{{ if { query:run query="SELECT left_bar form default_blog_meta where blog_id == {{query:run query='SELECT id from default_blog where slug = {variables:seg4}' }} "} }}
  {{ code }}
{{ else }}
  {{ code }}
```

It always goes to else condition as inner calls are not getting executed.

Comment: how is this a codeigniter problem?

Comment: PyroCMS is CodeIgniter based CMS.

Answer (score 1):

NO!

Lex is not a replacement for PHP. If you want to do that, put your query into your own plugin so you have a programming language to play with, instead of trying to make a tag representation system do it for you.

Please. Stop it.

Comment: Yes we are doing the same.

Comment: Teami, you might want to take a look at the codeigniter documentation about its MVC structure. you'll notice that PyroCMS is using the same approach in its modules and Lex tags..

It is important for both your web applications and yourself as a learning developer to remind yourself of keeping Data, Structure and Design strictly separated when using PyroCMS as your system of choice.